# aws ec2 linux instance not reachable

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created aws ec2 linux instance. I attached ebs volume and mounted         ebs under /mnt. I stored data under /mnt data size is huge. Now my instance is failed to respond ( checks failed ) but it is in running state. How can i restart server without loosing data that was stored under /mnt.

Note : ssh is not working cant login to the server . since instance not reachable.

I think AIM works but not 100 % sure. Is their any way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could stop and start your instance from the aws interface, you won't lose your data on your EBS.
If your instance is really broken, you can simply create a new one and attach your EBS volume to this new instance

Comment: once i tried same thing but result is failure i lost data that was stored under /mnt.

Comment: Did you use a ephemeral disk, or did you create an additional EBS volume, wich you attached, formatted and mounted? 
Also you can perform a snapshot of your EBS, so that even if your volume is lost, you will be able to recreate it

Comment: yeah i created ebs volume and attached it to instance and mounted under /mnt which is ephermeral . AIM image worked.

Comment: so is your problem solved? using ebs volumes, detach and attach a volume will not erase your data, this is 100% sure

Comment: You suggestion is correct. it worked. I tested it in normal micro instance.